# What is the difference between full mocking and partial mocking?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I'm currently working with mocking with Mockito using jUnit and I've stumbled upon the *Partial Mocking* section where you use Mockito.spy to *partially mock* the object. I don't seem to understand this concept of *partial mocking* since I can't find a scenario why I should use it (since it's pretty similar to mocking in general).

Can anybody explain how partial mocking differs from the normal mocking? And if possible, kindly provide examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Partial mocking is where you take a class and ask it to behave as normal, except you want to override certain functionality.
This is useful for unit testing services who communicate with other parts of your application. By overriding the behaviour that would call the other part of your application you can test your service in isolation.

Another example would be when a component would communicate with a database driver. By mocking the part that would communicate with the driver, you can test that part of the application without having to have a database.

Answer (score 2):

From the [EasyMock 2.2 classextension documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_ClassExtension_Documentation.html):

> Sometimes you may need to mock only some methods of a class and keep
>   the normal behavior of others. This usually happens when you want to
>   test a method that calls some others in the same class. So you want to
>   keep the normal behavior of the tested method and mock the others.

I sometimes use this to mock (complicated or process intensive) private methods that are allready fully tested.

Partial mocking can be very handy, but I try to avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Partial mocking:
Say you have a class which takes 10+ parameters for a constructor (this shouldn't ever happen but for this example lets say it does) it's a real chore to create that entire object. Frameworks like mockito let you just use the parts of the object you really want to test. 
for example

`@Mock BigClass big; //contains loads of attributes`

...

when(big.getAttributeOneOfTwenty()).thenReturn(2); //these are static imports from mockito

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful when I'm forced to work with APIs relying on inheritance from abstract classes and/or legacy code working with nonmockable static classes (one real life example - DAO).

Partial mocking (in sense of using the Spy facility from Mockito) allows you to mock calls to inherited methods in the first case, or wrap calls to static methods you are forced to use into normal methods that you can mock, verify etc.

Generally you should design and write code in such a way, that you won't need this (dependency injection, single responsibility per class etc). But from time to time it's useful.

A quick and rough example, to visualize the static API example:

```
class BigUglyStaticLegacyApi {
   public static Foo someStaticMethodFetchingFoo() {...}
}

class Bar {

   public void someMethodYouTest() {
      Foo foo = getFoo();
      //do something with Foo (a FooBar, for example :) )
   }

   /*this one you mock via spying - not the most elegant solution,
     but it's better than nothing */
   @VisibleForTesting
   protected Foo getFoo() {
      return BigUglyStaticLegacyApi.someStaticMethodFetchingFoo(); 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it the most to mock some methods in my CUT (Class Under Test) but not the method/s I'm actually unit testing. It is an important feature that should be used in unit testing with Mockito.